# Url Redirect to directory before

Tags: php, .htaccess

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /P5/

#existing rule
#remove the www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.co.uk$ [NC]

#new Rule
#if its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#and it has a trailing slash then redirect to URL without slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ def.php?p=$1 [L]
```

This is if I access some menu.

ex:home In my address bar is written this: `localhost/P5/home`, but if i add `/` after home: `localhost/P5/home/`

It is automatically redirected to : `localhost/home` and page not found appear

Anyone know this problem? thanks

Answer (score -2):

> but if i add / after home: `localhost/P5/home/` It is automatically redirected to : `localhost/home`

Well of course it is, because you have set `/P5/` as `RewriteBase`, and therefor

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

matches on `home/` only, and you redirect to captured part `home` with a leading slash, so it becomes `/home` – and a relative URL beginning with a slash always points to your domain, so the whole thing becomes `http://localhost/home`.

If you don’t want that – then *don’t* use a leading slash in front of your rewrite result.